# how to count the number of user logins by day, week, month

Tags: mysql

I’m using MySQL 8 and I'm trying to figure out (roughly) the number of unique users who login daily, weekly, monthly.

Here’s a the table for login data:

```
create table logins (
id mediumint not null auto_increment,
date date,
userId mediumint
primary key (id)
);
```

Desired output would be something like:

Daily 5
Weekly 15
Monthly 53

and it’s ok if this is 3 different sql statements.

By 'roughly', we are OK with the following definitions of daily, weekly, monthly

- daily = user has 5 rows or more per week
- weekly = user has 1 row every 5-10 days
- mostly = user has less than 3 rows per month

I tried something like this:

```
SELECT count(DISTINCT(userId)) as daily 
FROM (
SELECT userId, date,
timestampdiff(DAY, LAG(date, 1) OVER (PARTITION BY userId ORDER BY date ASC), date) as diff_days 
FROM logins GROUP BY userId) t1 
WHERE diff_days < 4;
```

but is isn’t producing what I’d wanted.

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your query is that it tries to calculate the difference in days between consecutive logins for each user and uses this to determine if the user is a 'daily' user. This approach would work if you were trying to categorize users based on how often they login consecutively, but it does not fit with your definitions.

There is my few tips

Daily Users

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as daily
FROM (
  SELECT userId
  FROM logins
  WHERE date >= DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 7 DAY)
  GROUP BY userId
  HAVING COUNT(*) >= 5
) as t1
```

Weekly users

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as weekly
FROM (
  SELECT userId,
    MAX(date) as max_date,
    MIN(date) as min_date,
    COUNT(*) as login_count
  FROM logins
  WHERE date >= DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 30 DAY)
  GROUP BY userId
  HAVING login_count >= 3 AND DATEDIFF(max_date, min_date) BETWEEN 5 AND 30
) as t2;
```

Monthly Users

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as monthly
FROM (
  SELECT userId
  FROM logins
  WHERE date >= DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 30 DAY)
  GROUP BY userId
  HAVING COUNT(*) < 3
) as t3;
```

Comment: Thanks Luboš - I appreciate how much more straight forward is your approach!